# Playing used UPlay Games

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-2, ubisoft-connect

So, my lovely girlfriend bought me a (used) copy of Assassin's Creed II for Christmas, and I finally got around to installing it today (what can I say, I also got Minecraft). Anyway, after installing from the DVD, creating yet another useless account with another useless service, I go to activate the game and I'm told the my access key is already in use by another account. The UPlay website says:

> "Uplay PC CD keys are unique and can only be used once. Once they are used, they are bound to the account that was logged in at the time of initial activation."

So, to my question: am I really as boned as it looks? Is there any way that I can play this game, or did we just buy ourselves a expensive coaster?

Comment: Best you can do is call Ubisoft's customer support, and see if they can help you out.  Or maybe the person you bought it from can provide the username and password.  If not, yeah, a coaster is what you got.

Comment: On 360 at least UPlay is just some external service with ubisoft which you can earn some points from various ubisoft games to unlock pointless extras. While its annoying you can't use it, have you double checked you can't actually play the game at all?

Comment: @djsmiley2k when I try to launch the game it just opens up the UPlay login screen. I'm playing on a PC.

Comment: I think you're hosed.  Kindly tell your girlfriend to never buy used PC games.  It's not worth the chance that they won't work.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Also, we can't help you here with the "otherwise" part of "ethical or otherwise", as we don't support piracy or DRM workarounds here. So unless there's a legitimate solution, we unfortunately can't provide you with other options, sorry!

Comment: @FAE fair enough, removed that part.

Comment: Nope. Ubisoft's DRM is the usual "No resales EVER" garbage along with happy fun intrusion and making a single player game entirely dependent on an internet connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are indeed boned, good sir.

The UPlay system has been designed in part to discourage used game sales. In order to gain access to this game on UPlay would require you to also gain access to the account it has been registered on, and in the process gain hold of the email registered to that account, etc. This would of course require you to track down the person which traded in the used copy and convince him to part with his account in which he may have registered other games that he may wish to keep.

Contacting Ubisoft will probably not help much. Their representatives are not obliged to help you in this matter. If they choose to help you, you are in luck. I would not count on it however. I think the greatest chance for a refund is for you to take the used game back to the reseller and explain the situation and hopefully get some form of refund.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't bother to contact Ubisoft, figured it was a waste of time. The re-seller was very apologetic and pointed me towards a refund, as they didn't have access to the UPlay account info - which was a long shot but I figured I might as well ask.